# Trying to solve for parameters in a logistic function

Tags: exponential-function

I am modeling a certain trend with a logistic function:

$$\begin{align}
y = \frac{1} {1 + e^{-k(x-X)}}
\end{align}$$

I have the value of $y$ at some point $x_1$:

$$\begin{align}
y_1 = \frac{ 1} {1 + e^{-k(x_1-X)}}
\end{align}$$

and I know that at $x = x_2$, $y = 2y_1$:

$$\begin{align}
2y_1 = \frac{1} {1 + e^{-k(x_2-X)}}
\end{align}$$

So I have 2 equations in 2 unknowns, but I can't figure out how to solve for $k$ and $X$ in closed form.

Is there a closed form solution?

Comment: do you know the values of x1, x2, and y1

Comment: please post them, or else you get ugly closed form expressions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do
$$y_1 = \frac{ 1} {1 + e^{-k(x_1-X)}}
\\ \frac 1{y_1}-1=e^{-k(x_1-X)}
\\ \log\left(\frac 1{y_1}-1\right)=-k(x_1-X)$$
and similarly
$$\log\left(\frac 1{2y_1}-1\right)=-k(x_2-X)$$
Dividing them gets rid of $k$ and leaves you with an equation in $X$ or define $kX=z$ and solve two linear equations for $k,z$

Comment: Thanks!  My circuits were really crossed.  I didn't see that.